# Cannot use map in factory pattern using c++

Tags: c++, factory

I am trying to create a basic type wrapper for a project and i want to use a factory to create types depending on the user input.

To illustrate this is my code for a Boolean type

```
class TypeBoolean :public GenericTypeWrapper<bool>, public ITypeWrapper
{
public:
    TypeBoolean(bool b = false)
{ 
   this->setValue(b);
    } 

std::string getTypeName()
{
    return "Boolean";
}

static ITypeWrapper* __stdcall Create(){ return new TypeBoolean(); }
};
```

The GenericTypeWrapper is just a class for the getters and the the setters and the ITypeWrapper class is just a abstract class with the getTypeName function in it

Now my problem is the factory

```
using createTypeFunction = std::function<ITypeWrapper*(void)>;
class TypeFactory
{
private:
static std::map<std::string, createTypeFunction> creationFunctions;

TypeFactory()
{

    std::vector<std::string> listOfTypeNames = { "Boolean" };

    std::vector<createTypeFunction> listOfCreateFunctions = { TypeBoolean::Create()     };

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < listOfTypeNames.size(); i++)
    {
        creationFunctions.insert(listOfTypeNames[i], listOfCreateFunctions[i]);
    }

}
};
```

Now there are obviously more types but the problem reproduces for just one type as well. I get an error on the following line

```
creationFunctions.insert(listOfTypeNames[i], listOfCreateFunctions[i]);
```

The error states :

```
error C2664: 'void   std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' to 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>'
```

I do not understand why i get this error thrown, so any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `map::insert` does not take key and value, but iterator and value_type.

Try this line instead:

```
creationFunctions[listOfTypeNames[i]] = listOfCreateFunctions[i];
```

Are you sure this line compiles without warnings:

```
std::vector<createTypeFunction> listOfCreateFunctions = { TypeBoolean::Create() };
```

Looks fishy to me, I would have expected `&TypeBoolean::Create` but maybe it's some new C++11 initializer feature I missed.

Comment: It does not have the same semantics as `insert` though. It might be worth pointing that out.

Comment: This was the problem, i have corrected it and now it works. And yes, the code sees no warning or error when using that initializer list.